# Unparsed Aapt Error

Tags: android, xml, image, src

I was trying to build my android application after adding an image, that i planned on using, to the drawables folder. 
The project worked perfectly fine before, but after running the project, an error message showed up saying, Unparsed Aapt Error. The error shows up on the src folder. 
I have tried to Clean my project but the R.java class just disapears.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem????

Comment: Without looking at the error, we will have no clue.

Comment: Remove image and see if this fixes it. If so, try re-saving image with any editor and then add it again to `drawable`.

Comment: Kumar - how do you want me to show you the error?

Comment: inazaruk-if i delete the image the errors go away soo it has to be something to do with the pic...

Comment: Am i adding it wrong cuz all i do is drag the pic into the drawables folder??

Comment: I had a similar problem today (unparsed aapt error), which was regarding a folder not being found on asset dir. I had deleted that folder, so it should indeed not exist, but for some reason Eclipse was finding it and trying to open. After 1h of debbuging, I found out that in my case it was a bug in Windows itself: the ghost folder would show up when I "DIR"ed the parent folder, but it wouldn't allow to open (not even admin). Then after a reboot it was all set (folder was 100% gone).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) clean project

2) close project

3) try again, if still fails: repeat 1 & 2 and then:

4) exit Eclipse and re-enter.

5) set the target in the run configuration to manual and try

There is a bug filed for this error - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14607

Till its resolved we need to bear with the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found another "fix" for this issue [in the Android Developer's Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bad9d488d2068260?pli=1) that explains that sometimes the error has been resolved but eclipse is simply unaware of it.

Apparently in this case you can also simply delete the error by right clicking it.

Comment: Hey Strongbad, why haven't you answered any emails lately?

Comment: Then you should kick him until he fixes it.  It was time for a new one anyhow.  Outdated technology--too pixely--you need good graphix.  Did you only answer this question so you could use the word "DELETED?"

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your **project > properties > android > in project build target : select android 5.0 with API level 21** or **select the same android version with api level which is set in android-support-v7-appcompat project.**

The api level and android version should be same in android-support-v7-appcompat as well as in your project.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** `Android SDK` or `Platform SDK` are not consistent with *Eclipse* plugin.

**Solution:**

1. Open Android SDK Manager and update: *Android SDK* & *Android Platform SDK*
2. Open *Eclipse* and update plugin

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these steps and nothing was fixing the appt error 138 that I was getting. As it happens, I was using TFS plugin at work and at some point the encoding of one of the xml file was changed from 0 on the server to ASCII on the local copy. I had to rollback to the last change set before the problem and then make sure to overwrite the offending file with the version from the server with encoding 0 to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases changing the image file qualifier from PNG's to png's will fix the Android "Unparsed aapt error(s)"

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem arises when we paste the image in drawable folder. The image name must contain only [a-z0-9_.] letters. I mean file names anywhere in "res" must only contain lowercase letters, numbers, or underscores. The link https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/beginners-android-app-help explains it very well.