# Android add image in res folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

When I try to add an Image in the `res folder` (I just copy the image and place it in respective folder ), and then when I build and run the project I get the below error message

> "Unparsed aapt error(s)"

And I can't run the project can anyone help me with this!

Comment: What is the name of your images???

Comment: remove spaces and CAP letters from Image name.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6767371/2982225)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you add an image to the `/res/drawable` folder, you need to go to `Project` -> and do a `Clean` and then build the project. I'm assuming that you've turned the `Build Automatically` option off.

Comment: I have another doubt, but can post my question after an hour :(

Comment: again, you are most welcome. please post your doubt as a separate question and i will surely take a look at it when i get a chance ... :)